# Kill a process after a certain amount of time in Apache Beam

Tags: rest, apache-beam

For every new user entry in a BigQuery table, I must send out an email to that user.

I'm using Apache Beam to get those entries from BQ and for each of them, I'm sending a request to a RESTful Web Service to send an email and waiting for the response.

Problem is, when the number of requests become too large say a million, the response from the web service comes very late and the Apache Beam job is in a hanging state.

Is there a way to just stop waiting for the response after maybe a minute and proceed with other requests in Apache Beam? Or will it just be better for the web service to send back a timed-out response after a minute?

I think the latter would make sense but I'm just curious to know if waiting is an option considering things run in parallel in Apache Beam.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the HttpClient properties with custom timeout parameters:

```
HttpParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, connectionTimeoutMillis);
HttpParams.setSoTimeout(params, socketTimeoutMillis);
```

The first param allows you to specify timeout establishing the initial connection and the second allows you to specify the maximum period of time in which a socket will wait while no data is sent.